# Property of the sample mean multivariate case

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, expected-value

I am trying to proof the next equality, considering $X_1,...,X_n$ random variables i.i.d. $$E||\hat\mu-\mu||^2=\frac{1}{n}tr(\Sigma)$$ where $\Sigma$ is the scatter matrix.
[image]

I have edited my post, I received the solution to the exercise, but I don´t have clear the third line and fourth line.

Because If I put inside the expectation in the second third line, I don´t have clear what happened with the crossed products in the second line?

For instance, in the second line I have a sum of random variables minus the mean, times a sum of the same random variables minus the mean, If I perform that product I will get some cross products, but in the third line and in the fourth line is only considered the products with identical index.

Could you explain it better, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "$\hat\mu$"?  Would it be $\hat\mu=(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)/n$? If so, then it looks like this result needs almost no work--it follows almost immediately from the definition of $\Sigma$. I wonder, then, what definition you are using?

Comment: In fact, the definition of $\hat\mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. COuld you explain what of my steps are not correct?

Comment: No, I don't care to study your steps, because there are enough of them that they indicate you're working harder than you need to.  I would prefer to suggest you look closely at whatever definition of $\Sigma$ you happen to be using and compare its diagonal elements (which sum to the trace, of course) to the left hand side of your question.

Comment: OK, acoording to the definition of scatter matrix, I have that is equal to $\Sigma=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^TX_i-n\mu^T\mu$. On the other hand I need to get $\frac{tr(\Sigma)}{n}$, here my problems I can´t find a relation between the trace of a matrix and my last expression. I don´t know what is wrong in my solution.

Comment: Specially this term looks strange, $(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)^2$ and the term given in the definition of the matrix $\Sigma$,  $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^TX_i$ because I know that $(a+b)^2\neq(a^2+b^2)$. In general I have some difficulties to figure out my computations as a matrix, Maybe this stuff is basic, but I have spent a couple of hours trying to understand it.

Comment: You seem to be using a definition of [scatter matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_matrix) for which the desired inequality does not hold. To appreciate the problem, consider random variables that equal $\mu$ almost certainly.  With your definition of the scatter matrix the trace is $n\mu^2$ but $\hat\mu-\mu=0$.

Comment: In this case which definition can I use?, Idon´t know another definition of scatter matrix.